# How can i make li elements be at the same level if the number or li elements is odd

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want the left li elemts to be at the same level with the ones in the right, here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/v5m6cv1u/

```
   <div class="menu">
</p>Code too long<p>
        </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "at the same level"?

Comment: Being even, in this exemple the second element continues to the right side , I want it to be only in the left side so the third can start in the top and it looks good.

Comment: What's the second element? Content? If so, why are you padding it so heavily?

Comment: The second li, the one with the class = "ipsum sit"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.menu h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4vh;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu h3 {
  font-size: 3vh;
  color: darkblue
}

.menu h4 {
  padding: 0.2em 0em;
}

.menu .content {
  padding: 3em 5em;
}

.ipsum {
  list-style: none;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

.menu p {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.menu .vitae {
  text-align: right;
  color: brown
}

.meniu .vitae:after {
  content: " VIT";
}

.menu .magna {
  text-align: right;
  color: darkslateblue;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.menu .magna:after {
  content: " MAG";
}

.menu ul {
  columns: 2;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu {
  background-color: #FFFAE7;
}

.menu h1 {
  color: #d00807;
  font-size: 6em;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 0.2em;
  padding-bottom: 0.1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et denique molestiae sit. </h2>
  <div class="content">
    <h3>Lorem</h3>
    <ul>
      <li class="ipsum dolor">
        <h4>Dolor</h4>
        <p>Nullam consequat, sem vitae rhoncus tristique, mauris nulla fermentum est, bibendum ullamcorper sapien magna et quam.</p>
        <div class="vitae">9.5</div>
        <div class="magna">320</div>
      </li>
      <li class="ipsum sit">
        <h4>Sit</h4>
        <p>Nullam consequat, sem vitae rhoncus tristique, mauris nulla fermentum est, bibendum ullamcorper sapien magna et quam.</p>
        <div class="vitae">9.5</div>
        <div class="magna">320</div>
      </li>
      <li class="ipsum amet">
        <h4>Amet</h4>
        <p>Nullam consequat, sem vitae rhoncus tristique, mauris nulla fermentum est, bibendum ullamcorper sapien magna et quam.</p>
        <div class="vitae">9.5</div>
        <div class="magna">320</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what did you change?:)

Comment: Look at .menu ul and .menu ul li and find the difference with the question. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Easy solution would be to make the element inline-block

```
.ipsum {
  [...]
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Absolutely Genius

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using columns on the `ul`, you could use this CSS on the `li`elements (it results in a different order, I don't know if that's okay for you?):

```
.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-right: 4%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w6br9r69/2/